# Big Data Conditional Agregration

Tags: sql, string, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a quick question that i'm trying to pound my head against with no success:

Let's say I have the following table:

```
+-----+----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
| Row | Promotion Name | Day | Month | Year | SENT | Open | Click |
+-----+----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
|   1 | Email_New_V1   |   1 |     2 | 2019 |    3 |    2 |     1 |
|   2 | Email_New_V2   |   1 |     2 | 2019 |    5 |    2 |     1 |
|   3 | Email_New_V3   |   2 |     2 | 2019 |    4 |    2 |     1 |
+-----+----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Basically, I want the totals of SENT, OPEN and CLICK for each day (day 1, day 2, etc...) and month (month 1, month 2, etc.)..aggregated by the first few characters in the Promotion name (Email_New%)

Basically, I would have this:

```
 +----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
    | Promotion Name | Day | Month | Year | SENT | Open | Click |
    +----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
    | Email_New      |   1 |     2 | 2019 |   12 |    6 |     3 |
    +----------------+-----+-------+------+------+------+-------+
```

I tried using SUBSTR to select the first few words, with no avail. Can I get a tip?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do YOU define "the first few words"?  What are other examples of promotions?  Why does your query combine data from two different days?

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Email_New_V1' promotion_name, 1 day, 2 month, 2019 year, 3 sent, 2 open, 1 click UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Email_New_V2', 1, 2, 2019, 5, 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Email_New_V3', 2, 2, 2019, 4, 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Email_Old_V1', 1, 2, 2019, 1, 2, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Email_Old_V2', 1, 2, 2019, 4, 5, 6 
), promotions AS (
  SELECT 'Email_New' promotion_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Email_Old'
)
SELECT p.promotion_name, 
  day, month, year, 
  SUM(sent) sent,
  SUM(open) open,
  SUM(click) click 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
JOIN promotions p
ON STARTS_WITH(t.promotion_name, p.promotion_name)
GROUP BY promotion_name, day, month, year
```

with output

```
Row promotion_name  day month   year    sent    open    click    
1   Email_New       1   2       2019    8       4       2    
2   Email_New       2   2       2019    4       2       1    
3   Email_Old       1   2       2019    5       7       9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the last 3 characters and group by the resulting string:

```
select 
    substring(promotion_name, -3) promotion_name,
    day,
    month,
    year,
    sum(sent) sent,
    sum(open) open,
    sum(click) click
from mytable
group by
    substring(promotion_name, -3),
    day,
    month,
    year
```

If there is a variable number of characters and you want to remove everthing after the last underscore (included), the regexp functions may come handy:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(promotion_name, '_[^_]+$', '') promotion_name,
    day,
    month,
    year,
    sum(sent) sent,
    sum(open) open,
    sum(click) click
from mytable
group by
    regexp_replace(promotion_name, '_[^_]+$', ''),
    day,
    month,
    year
```

`'_[^_]+$'` means: an underscore, followed by at least one character other than the underscore, then the end of the string.